# unittest output in IPython

Tags: ipython, python-unittest

I have a script for testing a module using unittest. When I run the script using the python
console I get the output:

```
test_equal (__main__.TestOutcome) ... ok
test_win_amount (__main__.TestOutcome) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

But, on running the same script using IPython console, I don't get any output.

I am using the following to run my script,

```
suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestOutcome)
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

Any ideas if this might be due to IPython settings?

Comment: I have the same question...

Answer (score 10):

Calling TextTestRunner with the stream parameter will make it work in IPython. This is how I run the tests:

```
suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(MyTest)
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=1,stream=sys.stderr).run(suite)
```